# Тулбар, влияющий на все View и паттерн MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется WPF MVVM приложение графического редактора.

Есть несколько View, у каждого из которых есть соответственно ViewModel'и, которые отвечают за редактирование свойств геометрических объектов.
В приложении имеется горизонтальный тулбар, кнопки и свойства которого влияют на все View.

К примеру есть кнопка "Показывать сетку", которая будет влиять на CanvasView отрисовки фигур (в этом View появится сетка), а также будет влиять на PropertiesView и т.о. при установленном флажке "Показать сетку" нельзя вручную задавать размеры и положение фигур в этом PropertiesView.
Т.е., получается, что CanvasViewModel и PropertiesViewModel зависят от свойства, которое не содержится в модели, но ссылку на которое они обе должны иметь.

**Вопрос**: Как лучше всего расшарить это свойство между ViewModel'ми (этих свойств в перспективе может быть несколько) и какие имеются подходы?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы сделал всё очень просто.

1. Глобальные параметры. Если установка «Показывать сетку» глобальная, значит, она принадлежит глобальным параметрам. Заведите отдельную VM с глобальными параметрами, и расшарьте её среди конкретных VM обычным образом (передача в конструкторе, DI, синглтон, статический класс, да как хотите).
2. Состояние кнопки на тулбаре биндится к нужному свойству из VM с глобальными параметрами.

---

Вопрос о том, как расшарить общую VM между разными другими VM ничем не отличается от стандартного вопроса, как расшарить объект между различными другими объектами.

Comment: а если кнопка на тулбаре принадлежит одному View? Кнопку можно забиндить к свойству глобальной VM, но как это обеспечит обновление всех View?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Ну, кнопка пошлёт команду глобальной VM, VM что-то обновит и оповестит остальные VM, они обновятся, и обновятся их View. Проблема связи между глобальной VM и другими <s>жалкими</s> VM — это внутренняя проблема уровня вью-модели, WPF и MVVM тут не при чём.

Comment: оповещение между ViewModel-ями конечно можно сделать. Но как при этом обновятся вьюхи? ViewModel  же не может обновлять свою вьюху, у нее даже ссылки не должно быть на нее? Паттерн издатель-подписчик использовать?

Comment: я работаю в Java Swing, все связи прописываю сам. Но суть от этого вроде не должна меняться. Да и получается не плохо. Но вот как вьюхи обновлять не могу понять.

Comment: а может такой вариант: сделать класс MainView, который просто будет содержать в себе LeftPanelView, RightPanelView, CenterPanelView (Композиция), а ToolBarView, кнопка которого должна влиять на многие другие View унаследовать от MainView? Тогда она получит доступ к LeftPanelView, RigthPanelView и CenterPanelView и сможет вызвать их методы bind,

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: С вьюхами проблем нет. VM обновилась → обновила свойство → отправилось `NotifyPropertyChanged` → вьюха подхватила автоматом через `Binding`.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: А, Swing, всё вручную :-\ В WPF обновление VM автоматом приводит к обновлению вьюхи, об этом заботится `Binding` (а внутри, да, `Binding` работает подписчиком на изменения VM, рассылаемые через `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Если мы говорим о WPF/MVVM, не совсем понятно, о каком методе `bind` идёт речь.

Comment: нет нет, не о WPF. Я в Swing реализую биндинг, создав методы bind и backBind. С этим у меня нет проблем. А вот как обновлять вьюхи.. Вариант с тем что бы вьюхи знали друг о друге плохой, да? Тогда нужно все общие данные, которые разделяют несколько View и которые должны синхронно обновляться слить в одну глобальную VM, реализованную, например, синглтоном. Она будет наследовать Observable. А те View, данные реализуют интерфейс Observer и подписываются на изменения глобальной VM. Скажите пожалуйста, хотя бы в правильном направлении мыслю?

Comment: Хотя, если использовать такой вариант, то все это начинает напоминать MVC. Только вместо того что бы подписываться на обновления модели, виды подписываются на обновления глобальной VM. Это так и задумывалось в паттерне MVVM. Или это у меня такой костыль получается?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Ну, мне сложно судить, как правильно в Swing'е, у меня не так много опыта. В WPF VM не знают о View, они выставляют возможность наблюдать за своими изменениями, а вьюхи должны сами следить и обновляться. Так ли это в вашей архитектуре, мне сложно сказать.

Comment: было не так, но теперь сделаю так. Нужно просто реализовать Наблюдателя. Спасибо вам!

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Пожалуйста! Рад, что смог помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Тут два варианта:

- Либо регистрируем вьюмодель тулбара как синглтон через IoC, большинство MVVM-Фреймворков это позволяют. [Например в Caliburn](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container)
- Либо реализуем синглтон по-старинке через статическое свойство.

Ну соответственно, как написал @VladD необходимые свойства хранить глобальными механизмами. Возможно с сохранением состояния между запусками и т.д.